# Adding new users/passwords to dictionary in python email application

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords

I'm having a bit of trouble with this program I've been working on for part of the final for my ITP 100 class. It's supposed to be an email application where you can log in if you are an existing user, or create a new username and password. I'm able to log into existing users with their passwords, and I can create a new username, but when I try to create the new password for it, I keep getting errors. I'm sure it's because I'm not updating the dictionary properly. I'm still pretty new to Python, so hopefully this all makes sense. Any advice?

- Also, my program seems to be stuck in an "if loop..?". Whenever I successfully log into an existing user, it show that I've been logged in, but will also go back to the original question "Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import re

users = {}
users={"nkk202": "konrad", "jfk101": "frederick"}

choice = None
login = None
createPassword = None
createUser = None
createLogin = None






print("Welcome to Kmail. The most trusted name in electronic mail.")
print("\nLet's get started")

while choice != "q":
    choice = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")

    if choice == "q":
        print("Thank you for using Kmail. Goodbye.")

    if choice == "n":
        print("Okay then, let's set up an account for you then.")
        createUser = input("Create login name: ")

        if createUser in users:
             print("I'm sorry, that username is already in use. Please try another!\n")
        else:
             createPassword = input("Enter a password: ")
             if len(createPassword) <5:
                    print("I'm sorry, this password is too short. Please try another.")
             passValue = {1:'Weak', 2:'Good', 3:'Excellent'}
             passStrength = dict.fromkeys(['has_upper', 'has_lower', 'has_num'], False)
             if re.search(r'[A-Z]', createPassword):
                passStrength['has_upper'] = True
             if re.search(r'[a-z]', createPassword):
                passStrength['has_lower'] = True
             if re.search(r'[0-9]', createPassword):
                passStrength['has_num'] = True
             value = len([b for b in passStrength.values() if b])

             print ('Password is %s' % passValue[value])
             users.update((createUser, createPassword))


    elif choice == "y":
        login = input("Enter your username: ")

        if login in users:
         password = input("Enter your password: ")

        if users[login] == password:
                       print("Welcome", login, "!")

        else:
            print
            print("I'm sorry, either the password/username was unaccaptable, or does not exist. Please try again. \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want

```
users[createUser] = createPassword
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you!!! Now I just need to get it out of that dang loop.